# Spring MVC- Getting error when I try to use proxyMode=ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I am using Spring 3.1 in a java web app

Now, as per this website--> http://tedyoung.me/2011/10/19/practi...rt-5-sessions/
I can use the following annotations for a Global Session scoped class..

Code:

```
@Component
@Scope(value="session", proxyMode=ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS)
public class UserPreferences {
....remaining code....
```

However, in my Java class, when I use the above annotations, I am getting this error in Eclipse IDE-->

> ScopedProxyMode cannot be resolved to a variable

What am I doing wrong here? I basically want to use a specific object across global session - viz, across multiple controllers in my Spring MVC based web app.

Comment: have you imported `org.springframework.context.annotation.ScopedProxyMode`?

Comment: @ArunPJohny no i did not :( please add your comment as an answer so that I can accept that as the solution... and thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think you are missing to import `org.springframework.context.annotation.ScopedProxyMode`.

Answer (score 0):

You should refresh your project and click ctrl+1 on your error line of code in eclipse and select package to import.Otherwise you should explicitly import org.springframework.context.annotation.ScopedProxyMode